# For Each loop NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, datagridview, foreach

I use a foreach loop to get data out of my datagridview using the following code.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridMultiSubmit.Rows)
{
    Model = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    Module = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    Section = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    FunctionValue = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    NewValue = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    DefaultValue = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    Description = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();

    MessageBox.Show(Model + Module + Section + FunctionValue + NewValue + DefaultValue + Description);
}
```

It returns all the rows correctly in the messagebox, but when it run trough all the rows it gives me NullReferenceException was unhandled, how can I fix this?

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Comment: Model = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If any one of those `Value`'s are `null` while you're iterating through all the rows, the call to `ToString()` will throw an exception.

Try instead:

```
Model = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value);
```

The method `Convert.ToString()` does an additional check.

- If the value is `null`, it returns an empty string.
- If it's not `null`, then it performs a `ToString()`.

---

From your comments, you also want to make sure you don't iterate over the new row that displays at the bottom of the grid. There's a built-in property called `IsNewRow`.

> Gets a value indicating whether the row is the row for new records.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridMultiSubmit.Rows)
{
    if (row.IsNewRow)
        continue;       // skip row, continue on to the next iteration

    ...
}
```

Comment: This works, however it also shows the empty line in the messagebox (the line in the datagrid where you can add a new line).

Comment: Isn't there a way to always ignore the last line? Otherwise it will always send this extra empty line to my sql database (used a messagebox to make the example simpeler.)

Comment: Yes, they need to be able to add rows, otherwise I could disable adding new rows.

Comment: @PandaNL: You could use a try{}catch{}-block and send the lines to your DB in the try-block. If the action fails (ie, the catch block is executed), nothing would be send to your DB.